# How to store data that could be set in one of 3 places with a hierarchy structure

Tags: database-design, data-structures, entity

Sorry if this belongs on DBA - I wasn't sure.

I have 3 entities: Website -> Store(s) -> StoreView(s). I will have a series of settings that could be stored at any one of these 3 levels. For instance, I could set a theme at a website level and it goes to all stores under that site, then it could be set at the store level which would in turn override the Website. I need to store this information in the database but I am not sure the best way to represent it.

I thought something along the lines of a table with the following columns:

`Name, Value, EntityType, EntityId` where `EntityType` would represent the Entity above and `EntityId` would represent the Id within that entity. This would just leave me to determine the entity hierarchy and get the information ordered by that.

Is this a scalable approach? I can't seem to think of a better way of doing this that wouldn't involve having lots of duplicated columns in the database.

**EDIT**

I have been looking into inherited tables and whilst I can see this would be useful for things like Contacts / Employees etc that share common attributes like FirstName, LastName etc, I don't think this is a good idea for things you might have a lot of fields for. For instance, what if I wanted to implement a message handler where you could set up user messages per website / store / store view? I would need a new column for each message which isn't practical.

Comment: abstraction, baby. check out table inheritance.

Comment: Oh, now that sounds interesting. Will do, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have an ERP system for project driven organisations and that has similar elements. For example, a sales condition can be set on:

- [system-wide](http://www.invantive.com/en/demo/web/bubs_isg_all.html)
- [customer](http://www.invantive.com/en/demo/web/bubs_lvr_all.html)
- [project](http://www.invantive.com/en/demo/web/bubs_pjt_all.html)
- [revenue](http://www.invantive.com/en/demo/web/bubs_obt_all.html)

The approach you suggest is feasible; we use it in some places but the correct implementation with ensuring data integrity takes some effort. Therefore I don't recommend it for general purpose use.

It is easier to duplicate the same column on all levels and then using the first applicable one by bubbling up the dependency chain (in your case: storeview -> store -> website) and maybe caching it.

If your question concerns multiple settings, you can either introduce a container of settings (which is similar to sales condition above; it contains contractual text, but also pricing, payment terms, etc).

If you want to be able to configure each property easily at each level of storeview/store/website, you can create an m:n table that joins a table like `PossibleProperties` with each of these three entities, leading to `PropertiesOfStoreView`, `PropertiesOfStore` and `PropertiesOfWebsite`.

If you also want to be able to configure each property on any object, then you have a business case for the suggested approach. But that is not common. In our project control system we have only done that for draft invoice lines (since they originate from processes, projects, revenues, conversion, timesheets, enfin you get the picture), documents (since they can be attached to many tables) and messages (since many table event can generate an email or a message to be forwarded to an external consumer).

Good luck! If this answer doesn't answer your question, please tell me what you are missing. If it is an answer, please let me know too by checking the hollow check mark.